# Foreach in Laravel with array of objects

Tags: laravel

I have an array of objects in my Laravel controller.  I need to loop over each object in the array and set the 'status' of each object to 0.  I have the following in my controller:

```
            if (request('status')=='Reset') {
            $allDemoTasks = DemoTask::all();

            foreach($allDemoTasks as $index=>$key) 
               $key->status=0;
               $key->save();
            }
```

It appears to be setting the last object in my array to 0 and not doing anything to the other objects.

Answer (score 3):

Your approach will make `count($allDemoTasks)` separate updates to your database. It is much better to do it in a single statement like:

```
DB::table('demo_tasks')->update(['status' => 0]);
```

or

```
DemoTask::query()->update(['status' => 0]);
```

Comment: Or even `DemoTask::query()->update(['status' => 0]);`.

Comment: @Tpojka For sure, I will add it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using eloquent

```
if(request('status') == "Reset"){
        App\DemoTask::all()
      ->update(['status' => 0]);
}
```

Comment: why would you hit the database again to retrieve the object you already have?

Comment: You took the original question, and added an unnecessary query to it.